# ES6, React, Redux forms. Trying to do something simple

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

G'day, I am trying to do something simple, and cant get a hold of it.

I have a number of forms.  A LOT of forms.  To keep my API succinct on the client I want to pass two state values into my client API.

```
import React, { Component }     from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm }     from 'redux-form';
import { connect }              from 'react-redux';
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { apiCreateData }        from '../actions/api';
import { CREATE_PERSON }        from '../actions/api';
import _                        from 'lodash';
The apiCreateData is a generic client side API which needs to simply call a server API with the form contents, a TARGET URI of the server REST API, and a constant "which type of action is going on".


//------------------------------------
class CreatePeople extends Component {
    //------------------
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            target: 'add_person',
            type: CREATE_PERSON 
        };
    }

I can see these in my REACT tools in Chrome.  The 'go' button calls this code.



    //----------------------
    onSubmit = (fields) => {
        console.log('onSubmit');
        console.log(fields);
        this.props.apiCreateData(...this.state, fields).then(() => {
            browserHistory.push('/');
        });
    }
```

I can not get those two bits of state into the receiving props in the client API.  I tried heaps of stuff!  Any help appreciated.
Cheers,

Mark.

Comment: The spread operator in function parameters doesn't work with plain objects. You have to pass the object itself as a parameter, or extract the values some other way.

Comment: Thanks.  If I wrap the thing in {} whole argument list, I do get it to the API in a nested object.  This would be OK for JS to JS interpretation, but the client API needs to talk to a Python API, so flattening the props is my concern!

Comment: What parameters does `this.props.apiCreateData` currently accept?

Comment: The API expect a bundle.  Or would like one.

//------------------------------------
export function apiCreateData(props) {

    const url = `${ASSET_INTEL}${props.target}/`;

    console.log('props in API : ', props);
    console.log('URL : ', url);

    const request = axios.post(url, props);

    return {
        type: props.type,
        payload: request
    };
}
`code`
This is then sent to the Python API.  I need it flatter than a two-dimensional object so Python can deal with it.  Ta.  It should be simple, I am missing something!

Comment: Sorry I tried to change the mark down but got a 5 minute error.  Try again

Comment: `//------------------------------------  
    export function apiCreateData(props) {


    const url = `${ASSET_INTEL}${props.target}/`;

    console.log('props in API : ', props);
    console.log('URL : ', url);

    const request = axios.post(url, props);

    return {
        type: props.type,
        payload: request
    };
}`

Comment: I can not get mark down to work!  Errrrkkkk.